# TSQL True/False IF ELSE Statement with CONTAINS

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to get a result of `True` or `False` by looking to see if my table contains a particular month and that meets some additional parameters.

SELECT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Semester FROM Courses
WHERE Language = 'English'
AND Post = 1
AND Year = YEAR(getdate())
```

Which returns data like:

```
Semester
-------
November 
October
```

I'd like to use `CASE` or `IF/ELSE` to determine if `October` exists in that `select` statement.

Something along the lines of:

```
IF (SELECT DISTINCT Semester FROM Courses
WHERE Language = 'English'
AND Post = 1
AND Year = YEAR(getdate())
CONTAINS(Semester, 'October')
THEN 'True'
ELSE 'False'
END IF
```

Which should give me `True` or `False` respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest doing something like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * 
                        FROM Courses 
                        WHERE language = 'English' 
                       AND Semester = 'October')
        THEN 'True' 
        ELSE 'False' END As Result
```

That should give you what you want and keep quick performance on large tables

Comment: Thanks @Dale_dale12 thats exactly what i was looking for. Will accept soon as the 5min timer is up